# System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out. while running test class

Tags: unit-test

I am getting the above error when I run the following test class:

```
     @isTest(SeeAllData=true)
    public with sharing class testCustomerSalesStatisticsController{
           public static testMethod void testCustomerSalesStatistics() {


                 Account a = new Account(Name='Tester', 
            AccountNumber='101552',
            Rating = 'Hot',
            NumberOfEmployees = 10,
            Description = 'test'
            );
            insert a;
Test.startTest();

               Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new WebServiceMockImplSIS()); 
               ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
               CustomerSalesStatisticsController OD = new CustomerSalesStatisticsController(sc);
               OD.CustNo = a.AccountNumber;
            //   OD.viewSISInfo();
               OD.getSISInfo();




           **MiddleWare__c mw = [SELECT id FROM MiddleWare__c WHERE name = 'esyconnector'];
            mw.Active__c = false;
            update mw;
            MiddleWare__c mw1 = [SELECT id FROM MiddleWare__c WHERE name = 'webmethods'];
            mw1.Active__c = true;
            update mw1;


             ApexPages.StandardController sc1 = new ApexPages.standardController(a);
               CustomerSalesStatisticsController OD1 = new CustomerSalesStatisticsController(sc1);
           //     OD1.CustNo = a.AccountNumber;
                  OD1.getSISInfo();**
           Test.stopTest();
    }
    }
```

Comment: If you have any workflow email alerts on the account object (or any object but in your case the account) you will get this error. Could that be the case? It is a known bug

Comment: best practice - get rid of `seeAlldata=true`; you or your successor may come to grief over this during a deployment. Mock all sobjects you need; only rare cases where this is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In salesforce you can not make dml and then do callout. This error comes when you try do to such things.
  BY calling getSISInfo method you are making callout and in test class for the first time it would be okay but in the same execution you have made dmls by below part of your code.

```
**MiddleWare__c mw = [SELECT id FROM MiddleWare__c WHERE name = 'esyconnector'];
            mw.Active__c = false;
            update mw;
            MiddleWare__c mw1 = [SELECT id FROM MiddleWare__c WHERE name = 'webmethods'];
            mw1.Active__c = true;
            update mw1;
```

And again in the same transaction your are calling getSISinfo means you are making callouts after dml.
If you want to solve this write separate test method to check different functionality.
Make sure that you are not making dml before making any callout. Before start method if you do any dml then that would be okay since salesforce will start context from start method.

Comment: But the same worked for me properly in another test class

Comment: @Pri Thats not possible. You can not make DML and then do a callout (unless you are using any extra workarounds to pass that.). Here is the doc which confirms that. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003701

Comment: @Pri You can check your test class error. You should be getting error at the point where you are trying to make callout after dml.

Comment: In case if I am using my DML above the start method then I am getting System.TypeException: Collection store exception error

Comment: @Pri At which line you are getting such error.

Comment: in mock class.I have made the update in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32871/discussion-between-kiran-machhewar-and-pri).